# Unable to launch firefox with X display fwd in localhost

Tags: ssh, 22.04, firefox, xorg

I'm trying to run firefox as another user from the terminal. Firefox errors out while VS code and gedit launch successfully. Also tried `firefox -no-remote` and `firefox -no-xshm`, got same error

Do I need some additional config to run firefox with display forwarding.

```
nraj@blade15:~$ ssh -XC user2@localhost
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.19.0-40-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is enabled.

0 updates can be applied immediately.



Last login: Tue Apr 25 17:00:26 2023 from 127.0.0.1
user2@blade15:~$ firefox &
[1] 104455
user2@blade15:~$ X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: cannot open display: localhost:14.0
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

[1]+  Exit 1                  firefox
user2@blade15:~$ code &
[1] 104613
user2@blade15:~$
```